# asp.net selecting a value from a dropdownlist and putting each selected value into a stack or list of a certain size

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Hello I'm relatively new to coding. I'm trying to teach myself how to do this but I've gotten stuck. I have a drop down list populated from a .mdf server, I'm trying to save the selected value from the drop down list to a spot on a stack of size 4, or maybe a list, I'm not sure which would be better when later in this thing I'm making, I want to make sure the selected items don't conflict with one another, how would I do this? I've tried it like this but Visual studio doesn't like it

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
   Stack<string> st = new Stack<string>(4); //I think this gives me a stack limit of 4?
   st.Push(ddl.SelectedValue.ToString());
lbl=st.ToString();

        }
```

I'm trying my best to understand how to do this stuff and thought it would be simple, but it is not simple for a beginner! Essentially what I want to do is, every time you select a thing from the drop down list, you click the submit button and it puts it onto the stack(or a list if you think that is better to use!) and shown on a label. I've tried similar methods to the above method and it only adds it once to the stack to the first spot in other methods. Thanks for anyone who can answer!

Comment: You are recreating the stack on each call to Click, if you want it to persist between calls then you must use the Session object, check if the Session already contains the stack, if that's the case retrieve it and add the new element, in other case create the stack, add the element and store it on the session.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. I think that this is out of my ability so I've moved onto another project and will come back to this later!

Answer (score 0):

First use a List.  Then you can call list.Add([value]).  Now you have to persist the list object between postbacks.  As Gusman said, you can save it to Session.  Now you can alter your code to check if the Session object exists, and init your list variable from the Session object.

It would look something like this:

```
    List<string> values;

    if (Session["Values"] != null)
    {
        values = (List<string>) Session["Values"];
        values.Add(value);
        return;
    }

    values = new List<string>();

    values.Add(value);

    Session["Values"] = values;

    return;
```